# Extending site.config with custom value not working

Tags: multisite

I am trying to get custom values for my site. So I've extended just the site.config with the "blubb" Attribute and "test12" value:

```
<site
      patch:before="site[@name='modules_website']"
      name="Shop-DE"
      hostName="sitecore.local"
      blubb="test12"
      targetHostName="sitecore.local"
      domain="sitecore.local"
      rootPath="/sitecore/content/SxpShop"
      startItem="/Startseite"
      virtualFolder="/"
      physicalFolder="/"
      language="en"
      database="web"
      allowDebug="true"
      cacheHtml="true"
      htmlCacheSize="50MB"
      filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB"
      enablePreview="true"
      enableWebEdit="true"
      enableDebugger="true"
      cacheRenderingParameters="true"
      renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
</sites>
```

In my code I am trying to get the custom value with:

```
var portal = Sitecore.Context.Site.Properties["blubb"];
```

but I get null because my new Attribute "blubb" is not in the "Properties" collection.

I am using Sitecore 9 update 2 and I've orientated me on this blog post: http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/add-custom-property-to-site-node.html

Comment: I am guessing it might not be in the context site that you expect it to be. You might want to check what is the current context site using Sitecore.Context.Site.Name

Comment: @FredricFoo yes it seems to be the wrong site. Is there a standard way how to check what is the current context site?

Comment: I had a similar need to have configuration specific to site context. This should do the trick if your SiteContext throws up the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be that the Context.Site is not responding the right site context.

with this Extension it seems to work. But I don't know if this should be the prefered Solution.

```
   public static SiteContext CurrentSiteConfig(this Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext context)
    {
        if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor || Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPreview)
        {
            var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
            var siteContext = SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(url.Host, url.PathAndQuery);
            return siteContext;
        }

        // standard context site resolution via hostname, virtual/physical path, and port number
        return context;
    }
```

Comment: The reason you need to do this is, that the Sitecore sites (the Content Editor, the Experience Editor and so on) run in the context of the `shell` site. So one way or another, you will need to check for this. The code snippet seems ok for this task.